# How to manage a growing drop down on my blog

Tags: html5

I have a blog and I add articles on it quite frequently. One caters to Short Stories and the other to Articles.

Not the drop-down has become huge and is covering most of the screen.

Can you please help me understand how I could customize it? I am using website builder, the latest version.I have added the picture as well for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Yikers. Why is everything so large? You could possibly reduce the gap between items, and instead replace with a divider or colour change of some sort between items.

Answer (score 3):

If that drop down menu is a list of articles, your best option is to stop using it. Menus like that exist for more permanent navigation options. (Home, About, Contact Us, etc)

A better option is to list your most recent articles from a location on the main page with either a synopsis or a short extract from the article. Although more frequently on blogs, articles are being displayed in full, one after the other in sequence. In a blog, the articles should be the primary focus and as such you want to give them the most real-estate on the page as opposed to relegating them to a small menu that is hidden most of the time.

**Unrelated**
I'd also like to give you a few suggestions regarding some of the other elements on that page.
I would strongly recommend removing the background image entirely. It can be very enticing to add images that you like, but a repeating background image like that adds a lot of noise to the page, subtracts focus from the rest of the content, and makes some elements hard to read/see.

You might also consider shrinking or moving the images at the bottom of that frame, as they clutter the design in their current configuration.

Comment: Yea, most blog platforms will give you the list of articles as a homepage. You don't need to add each article to the navigation. Other ways to organize your articles: By Topic, A-Z, By Date, By Author.